# SearchView suggestions: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener vs custom content provider (android:searchSuggestAuthority)

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I am trying to implement my first `SearchView` with suggestions. As far as I understand, I have two possibilities to provide suggestions:

1. In the `searchable.xml` configure a custom content provider using `android:searchSuggestAuthority` which is then queried for suggestions (system calls `query()` method on the specified custom content provider)
2. Or implement [`SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener?hl=en) and provide the suggestions via [`SearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView?hl=en#setSuggestionsAdapter(androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter))

Did I understand that correctly? Am I correct that the second possiblity gives me the possiblity to handle the search logic inside a `Fragment`/`ViewModel` without creating a content provider as required for the first possiblity?
Is there any advantage of one method over the other? Which one should I use? The [`Adding custom suggestions guide`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions) only mentions the first possiblity (using a custom ContentProvider), but that guide seems to be already quite old.